# Meaning of “times that for”

Tags: grammar, expressions, meaning-in-context, mathematics

I am proofreading an article for my friend and stumbled over the following sentence (boldface mine):

> *T* for the SM records was 0.67 **times that for** the AS records.

(The SM records and AS records are different datasets and *T* is a property of those datasets.)

Going by my observations of other articles, the bold part seems to be correct, but I wonder what it means.

Comment: It's fine, but how is it a question?

Comment: @Mick Would u mind elaborating on what italicized part means exactly?

Comment: What do SM and AS stand for?

Comment: @Mick maybe the OP means *issue*?

Comment: @Mick they are coefficients (say, mathematical issues)

Comment: @Sajjad: I edited your question to reflect your comments and some educated guesses. Please check whether everything is still according to your intentions. Also, please further [edit] your question to elaborate what you understood so far and where exactly your problems lie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original sentence:

> T for the SM records was 0.67 times that for the AS records.

Without more context, the following is what it appears to be saying:

> T for the SM records was **0.67 multiplied by the numeric value for the AS records**.

In other words, T for the SM records was that of the AS records multiplied by 0.67. It's possible that 0.67 here might actually be expressing a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring any question of linguistics as opposed to mathematics, it seems to be saying that T for the SM records was very roughly two/thirds of that for the AS records.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yeah I had the same thought pretty much and thanks for the confirmation.